# trouble with indices in summation proof

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

I have trouble with understanding the equations. What I'm fighting with is the fact that we sum over $a_{k+1}$ and begin with $k=1$ wich means that the first "$a$" appearing in the summation would be $a_2$. How do these equations end up with $a_1b_1$ where there is a $a_1$? Also in the second equation the first sum starts with $k=0$ transforming our initial $a_2$ in $a_1$. Guess I'm  overlooking something, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Just develop for very few terms. This is a classical way of changing the summations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term $a_1b_1$ is added and subtracted on the second line.

Comment: Of course. I even solved it correctly myself once.. concentration problems this morning. Thanks.